# Infinite loop after cin c++

Tags: c++, jdoodle

I'm pretty newbie at c++, so this confuses me.

This code seems to loop infinitely after `std::cin` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "My name is Martin. What's yours?" << endl;
    string name;
    cin >> name; //It seems to loop around here
    cout << "Ah, so you are" << name << "." << endl; //It doesn't print this message

return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm not sure I understand your answers, but what happens is that when you enter a name and press enter, it does nothing. The terminal just continues to the next line, letting you write something on that one too. It does this infinitely, a little bit like when you just press enter without any text.

EDIT 2: My bad, I should try to clear up things. This is what comes in the JDoodle console:

```
My name is Martin. What's yours?


 JDoodle - Timeout -  Some common reasons for Timeout 
Your Program may have a endless loop 
Please check the program and try again or contact JDoodle support at jdoodle@nutpan.com for more info.
```

The reason I believe it is a loop is that in a console that doesn't write timeout, I can continue to input on a new line all the time.

Comment: A blocked thread waiting for IO is not the same thing as an infinite loop.

Comment: You are supposed to type in a name and press enter. There should be a console window popping up somewhere waiting for you to do that.

Comment: Did you enter in any data?  [It works here if you do](https://ideone.com/vSpZRT)

Comment: Are you sure you are typing into the right console? Are you using an IDE or running your program directly in the console?

Comment: There seem to be something else is going on. This code should let you type and after return key it should close the console immediately. Are you actually running this code?

Comment: You need to enter in the text JDoodle expects in the `Stdin Inputs...` part

Comment: What NathanOliver and nwp mentioned regarding putting your input in `Stdin Inputs...` should make it work. Please add a tag of `JDoodle` to your question.

Comment: @Griffin unfortunately, there is no JDoodle tag yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-compiler-c++) the console will be waiting on the server. If you don't type anything there it hangs until it eventually gets killed for being too slow.

The way to fix this is to enter the text you wish to type before running the program into the box labeled "Stdin Inputs...".

Alternatively you can set the "Interactive mode" to "On" which will show the console in the website where you can enter some text and press enter. (I tried, it works).

Comment: If you are unable to enter the text check if you blocked the interactive shell with NoScript or some other browser setting.