# C++ Program works when using int with cin but not a string

Tags: c++, string, cin

I wrote this simple program to more or less "warm up" in using C++ and when asking for a string input, the program stops working as intended.

Here it is asking for an int, which works as intended:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "enter something\n";
    int usertypestuff;
    cin >> usertypestuff;
    cout << usertypestuff << " is a number.";
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\fortm\Documents\CPPPrac> cd "c:\Users\fortm\Documents\CPPPrac\MainPrac\" ; if ($?) { g++ Main.cpp -o Main } ; if ($?) { .\Main }
enter something
12.5
12 is a number.
PS C:\Users\fortm\Documents\CPPPrac\MainPrac>
```

However, when changing code to use a string instead, the program skips over "enter something" and the cin lines and jumps to a new line (for commands and etc.) instead.

Non-working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "enter something\n";
    string usertypestuff;
    cin >> usertypestuff;
    cout << usertypestuff << " is a number.";
}
```

Output log:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\fortm\Documents\CPPPrac> cd "c:\Users\fortm\Documents\CPPPrac\MainPrac\" ; if ($?) { g++ Main.cpp -o Main } ; if ($?) { .\Main }
PS C:\Users\fortm\Documents\CPPPrac\MainPrac> 12
12
PS C:\Users\fortm\Documents\CPPPrac\MainPrac> hu
hu : The term 'hu' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ hu
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (hu:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\fortm\Documents\CPPPrac\MainPrac>
```

I've tried compiling with both MinGW and CygWin to no avail and am running the program with coderunner (run in terminal is checked) in Visual Studio code.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please rephrase what do you want to do? I'm having difficulties to understand.

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working (a [mre]) and can you explain what `causes the program to instead look for a command instead of running the program` means?

Comment: `std::cin` stops taking input after encountering whitespace. You should ensure your string does not have any whitespace in the beginning. To take input with a whitespace, use `std::getline (std::cin,usertypestuff)`

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to input a multi-line string? As mentioned the `>>` operator will stop reading at any white-space, which includes newline. When you have pressed the `Enter` key the program will read the line and (for `>>`) get the first "word" from that line. Then the program will print its output and exit, leaving any other lines you might enter as input to the console or shell. If you want to read a single line then use a single `std::getline` call (again as mentioned), otherwise use `std::getline` in a loop to read all lines.

Comment: like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115961/infinite-loop-after-cin-c
maybe Cygwin interactive mode setting.

Comment: By the way, please [edit] your question to tell us *how you **run** the program*.

Comment: I suspect the input is a sentence that contains a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> usertypestuff;
```

The `std::operator>>(std::istream&, std::string&)` method reads from the stream until it finds a space, and then returns.  Then the rest of the program runs.  Your code is fine, but I suspect that while running the program in a terminal, you're entering an input that has a space in the middle.  The program reads up to the space, then finishes running correctly, and then exits. After that, the terminal reads the rest of the input as the next program to run. But since your input wasn't a valid command, the terminal displays a `CommandNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine when i did it..

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "enter something\n";
    string usertypestuff;
    cin >> usertypestuff;
    cout << usertypestuff << " is a number.";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
enter something
25
25 is a number.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::to_string()` function to convert *usertypestuff* to string,

```c
string str = to_string(usertypestuff);
```