# VS code c++ cin not working with string type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cin

This is a simple hello program, but it shows nothing if I run it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    string username;
    cin >> username;
    cout << "hello, " << username << ", ..., goodbye\n";
}
```

output:
nothing in the terminal

The single cout can work, so I guess that might be the problem with buffer caused by string.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    //string username;
    //cin >> username;
    //cout << "hello, " << username << ", ..., goodbye\n";
}
```

output:

```sh
Please enter your name:
```

But adding `flush` doesn't make it work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    string username;
    cin >> username;
    cout << "hello, " << username << ", ..., goodbye\n" << flush;
}
```

output: nothing in the terminal

Then I change the type of `username` to `char, int`, and they all work properly.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    char username;
    cin >> username;
    cout << "hello, " << username << ", ..., goodbye\n";
    
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    int username;
    cin >> username;
    cout << "hello, " << username << ", ..., goodbye\n";

}
```

output:

```sh
Please enter your name: asdf
hello, a, ..., goodbye


Please enter your name: 123 
hello, 123, ..., goodbye
```

The above are run by code-runner, so I try to compile manually, but it still doesn't work.

```sh
DINO@DINO-Amadeus MINGW64 /d/DINO/code/essential_c++
$ g++ -o chap1 chap1.cc

DINO@DINO-Amadeus MINGW64 /d/DINO/code/essential_c++
$ ./chap1

DINO@DINO-Amadeus MINGW64 /d/DINO/code/essential_c++
$
```

Can anyone help with this? Many thanks.

Comment: @JaMiT edited, could you have a look the issue now?

Comment: Your last test case can't compile (multiple variables with the same name), and even if it did it certainly would not produce the output shown (entering `asdf`, the first `>>` would read only `a`, leaving `sdf` to be read by the second `>>` and fail).

Comment: The code works for me (well, aside from having to split your last example into two programs), and I don't see undefined behavior lurking here. So there must be something else going on.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau But these are just insignificant invalid inputs. The real problem is that the very first program can compile but does not allow me to input.

Comment: @KOMAX233 [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/uzePG8). By default, `cin` and `cout` are supposed to be `tie()`'d together, so that reading input will first flush any buffered output. What you describe makes me wonder if maybe they are not tied together on your system, for some reason. In any case, in your `flush` example, you are flushing in the wrong place. Do it after the 1st `cout` and before the `cin`, not after the 2nd `cout`: `cout << "Please enter your name: " << flush;`

Comment: What happens if you try to compile a program that has syntax errors? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Also, are you entering any non-English characters?

Comment: I tried compiling and running your first code with MSVS 2022 version 17.10. It compiles and works properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to compile your *first* example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << "Enter name" << endl;
  string username;
  cin >> username;
  cout << "Hello, " << username <<  ", goodbye\n";
}
```

and have it work in Codeblocks' console as expected.

```
Enter name
John Doe
Hello, John, goodbye

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.623 s
Press any key to continue.
```

It also compiles manually through cygwin.

```
*****@DESKTOP-******* /cygdrive/c/Users/*****/Documents/Programs/Test/test
$ g++ main.cpp -o main

*****@DESKTOP-******* /cygdrive/c/Users/*****/Documents/Programs/Test/test
$ ./main
Enter name
John Doe
Hello, John, goodbye
```

All this makes me think the code is fine, and the real problem is elsewhere. You said you are using coderunner. Is this for a class? You might be able to see what other students are doing different.

EDIT 10/9/2021
Lets try the following to see what is messing up:

1. Whether the problem is with the namespace, see if the below code works: (If you type "Hello", it will print "Hello")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
  std::string username;
  std::cin >> username;
  std::cout << username;
}
```

2. To see if the problem is with cin, try this (It should output "Hello")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string username = "Hello";
  std::cout << username;
}
```

3. And, as a moonshot: (Same behavior as (1))

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char* username[5];
  scanf("%s",&username);
  printf("%s",username);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no it's not for a class.. I find [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166889/c-program-works-when-using-int-with-cin-but-not-a-string), but it seems no one really answered that..

Comment: Probably because noone could figure it out there either. Lets see if we can narrow it down at least. I am adding an edit with some things to try, that will at least help see where the problem is originating.

Comment: `operator>>` stops reading on whitespace, so there is no way `cin >> username` can return `John Doe` as you have shown, it would return `John` instead. To read in a string with spaces in it, you would have to use `getline(cin, username)` instead.

Comment: Also, your example is not *exactly* the same as the OP'S 1st example. You added `<< endl` after the `cout` prompt. That will implicitly `flush` the output buffer.

Comment: You're right, I tried using it as well, and may have pasted that. It is fixed.

Comment: I left the <<endl, however; it doesn't change the output. I had been trying different things to see if something would do as the OP described. I may have not pasted the exact code.

Comment: I have this char array method work while the others don't. ```char A[100];

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> A;
    cout << "You entered: " << A;```

Comment: I tried `getline` as well                                                                                                                                    ```string str;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, str); 
    cout << "You entered: " << str;``` and it does not work, so I guess the problem is with using `string` object?

Comment: Possibly. In which case `string username = "Hello"; cout << username;`?

Comment: Also, at this point, it may be a good idea to include details about your "toolchain" you used for compilation; someone here may be able to help you troubleshoot there. The code you are trying to run _should_ work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the extension of VSCode which runs your code, and update to the latest version if you can. If you are using `.run`, try `C/C++ Compile Run` by danielpinto8zz6 or similar.